# PyMySQL Internal error: packet sequence wrong

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, pymysql

I recently reinstalled my Raspberry Pi and wanted to use flask with a mariadb / mysql database again. Everything went fine until I wanted to actually access the database. flask uses pymysql as far as I know and everytime I want to get the cursor for the database, I'm getting an internal error: package sequence number wrong.
It worked fine before I wiped my RPi and I think I'm using the same configuration as before.

The error comes from pymysql itself because with the following code it also doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                user='root',
                                password='passwd',
                                db='mysql')
```

I'm still new to mysql and I'm not sure what is going wrong here.
From the commandline I can access the empty database just fine. As the database is still empty maybe reinstalling mariadb would help?

Comment: Can you provide version of PyMySQL and your database server? Do you use MariaDB or MySQL server?

Comment: I‘m using mariadb 10.3, pymysql 0.9.3 and Flask-MySQL 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

The default password for root is empty in maria db so try changing that, maybe it'll work

password = ""

Comment: This is not a answer. This belongs in the comment section of this question and not as an answer itself. Please act accordingly